# Sharing data accross appdomains, running linq queries on both sides, and beyond

Tags: c#, .net, linq, appdomain, dynamic-compilation

To start from the beginning, I'm working on an utility to parse and review logs from a third-party application, with an explicit requirement for extreme flexibility.

In order to achieve that, I'm squeezing LINQ to its full potential (and possibly beyond that :/ ).

Since the user is supposed to build their own queries through the utility's UI, I need to be able to load and unload them dynamically. To this purpose, I'm building dummy classes with a single method (literally named "DoStuff") that returns the result of the query (often LINQ-based, but there may be exceptions), compiling them (via a CSharpCodeProvider) into temporary assemblies, loading them on a "disposable" AppDomain, running the query, and then getting rid of the AppDomain and assembly.

And here is where the alarms fire: LINQ + AppDomains = lots of opportunity for problems to arise.

To make things worse, it can get really tricky to know for sure what will be running on each domain, and what will be crossing (or trying to cross) domain boundaries. I hope the knowledge pool in stackoverflow can help sheding some ligth over this.

So, deep into the specifics, here is a simplified version of what I have:

On the main assembly (the actual .exe file for the utility), which will only be loaded the "normal way" by the user executing it, I have something that resembles this:

```
public abstract class LogEntry { // Should this inherit from MarshalByRefObject?
    protected internal abstract void Parse(StreamReader input);
    ...
    /* There are literally dozens of classes that inherit from LogEntry, dealing with different kinds of entries, and
     *   defining an appropriate implementation of Parse().
     * The logic to choose the appropriate sub-class would be within LogData's constructor (see below).
     */
}
internal class LogData: IEnumerable<LogEntry> { // Should this inherit from MarshalByRefObject?
    private List<LogEntry> loadedData = new List<LogEntry>();
    public LogData(IEnumerable<string> LogFiles) { ... }
    /* The enumerator for this class does some heavy-dutty work to find the log files and load them "as needed":
     * Each time a new entry is retrieved from the logs, it's saved on loadedData just before returning it;
     * When the enumerator is reset and used again, it goes through loadedData until exhausting it, and only then
     * goes back into actually loading (and saving) new data.
     * I'm not including the code here because it is ugly, verbose, and probably irrelevant to the question.
     */
}
```

(aside from some forms, boiler-plate startup code, etc). The program will request the user to provide a collection of log files (using FileOpenDialogs, text fields that support file-name patterns with the classic "*" and "?" wildcards, etc), and use them to initialize a single instance of LogData.

After that, the user is presented with a shinny GUI to build and fine-tune queries, including a Doom's Day Button to run the query. And that's where the fun begins. The idea is to generate the code to represent the user's query, then wrap it into something like this (I have omitted the "using" statements and other side stuff here):

```
public class whatever { // I'm thinking of making this static and saving on the constructor invokation work, but that's a side topic.
    public IEnumerable DoStuff(IEnumerable<LogEntry> Input) {
        // This will be filled with code created on-the-fly based on user input
        ...
    }
}
```

This is then feed to a CSharpCodeProvider to compile it (with a pre-defined, configurable list of references) into a temporary assembly. Then I load the assembly into a "throw away" AppDomain, create an instance of "whatever", invoke its DoStuff method (passing it my instance of LogData), retrieve the results, unload the domain, and get rid of the assmebly.

Now, what will be happening under the curtain? That's the actual question ^^. It is rather tricky to track what code is running on each domain, and what data is bouncing back and forth between them. After some research, I'm making some educated guesses, so it would be enough if someone can tell me whether I got them right or not:

1, LogData would have to inherit from MarshalByRefObject, so when it's passed to the user's query (DoStuff), the enumerator still executes on the "default" appdomain and things work properly.

2,) The above means that no LogData instance ever crosses AppDomain boundaries (calls to its members are another story), but its entries (LogEntry instances) do when the log is iterated from DoStuff. So, should those be serializable? They wouldn't be hard at all to de/serialize, although I feel that'd be like doubling the parsing work. Would it work to make them MarshalByRefObject descendants instead?

3, Whatever DoStuff returns, it will need to be copied, not referenced, so it can still be used from the main AppDomain after unloading the "throw away" one. So any type the queries could include on their results will need to be serializable and never MarshalByRefObject.

4, Even if DoStuff returns a LINQ query (with something like "return from entry in Input ..."), the query's enumerator will only be running on the "throw away" domain, and only the individual items (which, on the point above, I have already said that those should be serializable anyway) will actually cross domain boundaries.

Are these conclusions right? Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance for any answer.

P.S: Based on Daniel's comments below, I guess I'll have to go a bit deeper on some aspects about the project:

1. While the "query builder" is aimed to be the main mechanism to define queries, the program will also let the user introduce raw code when the builder just isn't enough (and also for those users familiar enough with programming that would prefer typing some code over navigating around drop-downs, menus, and other fancy stuff; which happen to be a significant chunk of the project's target audience).
2. Another feature I didn't mention is that it will enable saving queries for later use. With queries represented by C# code, persisting them is trivial (prior to compilation, they are just strings). Persisting expression trees (or anything resembling them) can quickly turn into a big hurdle.
3. This is not the first time I dive into the `CodeProvider` classes; dynamically loading assemblies; nor LINQ. But it's probably the first time I go as deep as I am going with this; and definitely the first time I try to put all of these together. I am familiar with the potential of each of these features, and rather confident that what I am trying will be relatively easy once the tricky details about their interaction are sorted out. This question is only about those details, I can handle everything else from there.

Comment: Why not simply load it into the same appdomain? Are those queries changing that often that you will get a problem, because you loaded too many assemblies?

Comment: The main focus of the tool is on building and running queries, so definitely there will be a lot. Aside from the memory and other potential costs, there is an issue of name-clashes (solvable, but tedious) and dangling files (the assembly can't be deleted while loaded).

Comment: name clashes can be solved without problems, just append a `Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N")` to the name. Assemblies can be created completely in memory, no need to safe them to the disc. But **if** there are a lot of queries and each will be compiled into its own assembly, I agree, that it is not the best way, to leave them all in memory...

Comment: Another thought: Is it really necessary to work with compiling your own assemblies? Can't you build these dynamic queries with normal methods? Without knowing how your queries look like, I am still pretty sure, it should be possible.

Comment: On the in-memory topic, I have tried that and I'm still trying to figure out why the assembly files are being created regardless of asking the code provider to create them in-memory :(  
Regarding your other comment, see my edit to the question.